state not updating immediately in next.js
i am passing a callback function from the parent to the child (Searchbox) the set the state to the search query and then use the query as an argument in the post request which is a custom hook (usePost) and setting the state(filteredData) to the response from the request everything is working fine except one thing the state is always 2 steps behind except the state in SearchBox component is up to date also the paylod in the request made is the second previous state.
this is the parent
'use client';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import CouponsCategories from '@/components/coupons/CouponsCategories';
import SearchBox from '@/components/coupons/Search';
import PaginationComponent from '@/components/coupons/PaginationComponent';
import getApiUrl from '@/utils/api';
import { CouponsFilter } from '@/components/coupons/CouponsFilter';
import useGet from '@/hooks/useGet';
import { ErrorMessage } from '@/components/coupons/ErrorMessage';
import Loader from '@/components/coupons/Loader';
import usePost from '@/hooks/usePost';

const CouponsPage = () => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(undefined);
  console.log(filteredData);
  const mainUrl = getApiUrl();
  const {
    data: coupons,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useGet(mainUrl + 'free-udemy-courses');

  const filterApi = `${mainUrl}filter/udemy-coupons`;

  // usePost hook to make API request
  const { data, postRequestError, postData } = usePost(filterApi);

  const handleSearch = async (query) => {
    setSearchQuery(query);
    await postData({ searchQuery });
    setFilteredData(data);
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <ErrorMessage>Failed to load coupons, please try again</ErrorMessage>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className='block w-full mx-auto'>
      <SearchBox onSearch={handleSearch} />
      <CouponsCategories />
      <div className='flex p-2'>
        <CouponsFilter />
        <PaginationComponent coupons={filteredData ? filteredData : coupons} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CouponsPage;

this is the search component where i am taking the input and updating the state in the parent
import { useState } from 'react';
const SearchBox = ({ onSearch }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
      onSearch(query);
      console.log('query', query); // Invoke the callback function passed from the parent
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className='my-4 w-[800px] mx-auto'>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='Search...'
        className='w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500 h-14'
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} // Handle key press event
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchBox;

this is the custom hook used to make the request

const usePost = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [postRequestError, setPostRequestError] = useState(null);

  const postData = async (requestData) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to post data');
      }

      const responseData = await response.json();
      setData(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      setPostRequestError(error.message);
    }
  };

  return { data, postRequestError, postData };
};

export default usePost;

